# Magento updating database manually not working

Tags: magento-1.9, database, model, jquery

I'm trying to manually update a column "term" in a table named "adyen_subscription" via a primary key "entity_id".

I followed this in calling the table: `Mage::getModel('namespace_modulename/tablename')`

AJAX:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/scripts/edit.php?entity_id=' + diaper_size,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".success-subscription-message").html('<p>Edit Successful</p>');
        },
        error: function(data, status, error) { 
            alert(error);                          
        }  
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$entity_id = $_GET['entity_id'];

$subscription = Mage::getModel('adyen_subscription/subscription')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$entity_id);

foreach ($subscription as $item) {    

    $item->setData('term', $frequency);  
    $item->save();   
}
```

There were no errors, but the database wasn't updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `saveAttribute` method.

In your example, you could load the model with the `entity_id` if it is the primary key by simply using:  `$model = Mage::getModel('adyen_subscription/subscription')->load($id);`

Then set the data item using one of two ways: `setTerm('new term')` or `setData('term','new term')`

If there was a magic method override for `setTerm(...)`, then this could explain part of the issue, so trying with `setData('term','new value')` may work.

Once, you have set the new value, then you can do:

`$model->getResource()->saveAttribute($model, 'term');`

This should update that specific column with the column name `term` using the value that the model has currently set.

---

**Side Note:**

Get into the habit of using Magento's wrappers instead of PHP super-globals.  If you are developing within Magento, using PHP over Magento wrappers is by-passing functionality that is the actual Magento Framework.

`$entity_id = $_GET['entity_id'];` should be:

`$entity_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');`

or depending on what class you are inheriting from, you may:

`$entity_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');`

Comment: I see, thank you for the suggestion! load(), setData(), and save worked for me! Thanks for the side note as well, I did not know this was possible :)

Comment: If this solution resolved your issue, then you can check it as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Adyen Subscriptions extends from Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, so the answer can be valid for most Models.
You can use magic methods:

```
Mage::getModel('adyen_subscription/subscription')
->load($entity_id)
->setTerm($frequency)
->save();
```

Why wasn't your script working? You should debug it. Is `$frequency` defined? Is its type valid for the database field?

However, beware that with this implementation anybody could call your php script giving any (and all) entity_ids as input.

Comment: Thanks! load()->setData('term', $frequency) worked for me!